# How can I create an online database?

Tags: database

I want to create a database. My laptop is having some problems, so I cannot use Microsoft SQL 2008 to make databases. Is there any software that can help me create a database online?

Comment: Uhh yeah, there is plenty of database software out there...

Comment: sqlite cannot use because it is local database, Microsoft SQL Server Express 2008 my laptop cannot install i got no idea

Comment: What about MySQL, PostgreSQL, and a bunch of other stuff?

Comment: i was using mysql to created, now the problem is Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.41 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.12. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a database service that is free and online, just use your favourite search engine to look for "free database mysql" or "free database sql server".

Alternatively, if you would like to have a database server running on your laptop, you could perhaps install Microsoft SQL Server Express (you didn't mention which edition) from http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/ or you could install MySQL from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Express 2008 gave me an error when install

Comment: What was the error message? Did you take any steps to try and resolve that?

Comment: a particular file is missing then cannot install already

Comment: Ok. It seems as though you want to have a database server available via the internet (you keep saying you need a database server online). I'd suggest checking this place out (I have absolutely no affiliation - I just searched google): http://www.db4free.net/. They allow you to setup a database online, for free. The syntax isn't very different from Microsofts version of SQL, and you haven't specified what you need, so that should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many RDBMS out there in the wild, Go with MySQL, http://mysql.com

Comment: i download mysql server 5.5 but seem like cannot create database in the server there

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express

It was suggested to me, but I wound up just connecting through my visual studio suite.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B

Comment: i cannot install, it prompt out a error, i got no idea

Comment: You can at least provide us the error

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree about their being million of databaes out there, this question could really have been thought out more throughly.

But mysql  www.mysql.org and postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/ are argueably the most popular. sqlite is also strong for small projects.

I cannot really say if it is the right solution or not, but google app engine may be a solution if you are building a webb app

Comment: my application cannot use sqlite because it need deal with server so need database online